# Firebase login with custom auth token does not expire after 1 hour

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-security

I have a react app where I am able to login with custom token as follows:

```
  await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(tokenResp.token);
```

As per [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk), firebase custom jwt have one hour expiry. And this is what I expect.

But when I make calls to collections that require authentication(i.e. `request.auth!=null` via firestore rules) after 1 hour, I am able to access them. I would expect the firebase instance to fail(automoatically) after one hour for these calls.

So why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Also note that I have logged in the jwt used to authenticate and clearly the expiry date is one hour by looking at the `exp` field in jwt decoder.

Answer (score 4):

When the documentation states that the Custom Token (`tokenResp.token` in your case) is valid for one hour, it means that the `signInWithCustomToken` call must happened within one hour after token creation. Once the user is "signed in" (using any of the `signInXXX` methods), they get an access token and a refresh token, which can be used indefinitely until sign-out or revocation.

It sounds like you're trying to use Security Rules to limit access to users who have signed in within the last hour. To achieve that, inspect the `auth.token.auth_time` field which contains when the user has authenticated (in seconds since epoch). For example: `request.time < timestamp.value(auth.token.auth_time * 1000) + duration.time(1, 'h')` evaluates to `true` if the request time is within one hour of sign-in time. You can use that in place of `request.auth!=null`.

In addition, you can automatically sign users out after one hour on your client side, say using JavaScript timers and checking `(await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()).auth_time` as well. (Please note that this merely improves user experience on the client side and is not a substitute for the Security Rules, since client code cannot be fully trusted.)